# In a polynomial, if $p(x)$ is divisible by $x$, why is the constant $0$?

Tags: polynomials

Here's the problem.

$p(x) = 3(x^2 + 10x + 5) − 5(x − k)$

In the polynomial $p(x)$ defined above, $k$ is a constant. If $p(x)$ is divisible by $x$, what is the value of $k$?

In the answer it explained that because "$p(x)$ is divisible by $x$" we know that the constant is $0$. But why is that true and what is the constant?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider cases where the constant term is not zero, or try expressing $p(x) = x q(x)$ and see what the multiplication of polynomials implies.

Comment: I don't know what the constant term means. As I said below, I don't know what p(x)=xq(x) is.

Comment: The constant term of a polynomial is the monomial that corresponds to the zero power of $x$. $x q(x)$ means the polynomial product of $x$ and $q(x)$.

Comment: So your saying that if x is 0, the output of the polynomial is equal to the constant? Example: 2x^2 + x + 5       5 is the constant and if x is 0, 5 is the output.

Comment: That is true, although I was not thinking of that when I commented.  It is a good way to think about the constant term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is a quadratic and a quadratic  can only have linear factors, one which you specified is $x$, the other we will call $L(x)$

$$xL(x)=3x^2-25x+5k+15$$

Set $x=0$ to get:

$$0=5k+15$$

Another way you can think about it:

When you divide your polynomial by $x$ you get:

$$3x-25+\frac{5k+15}{x}$$

The numerator of  last term is a remainder and we need to get rid of it by setting it equal to zero.

$$5k+15=0$$

$$k=-3$$

Answer (score 0):

That means $P(x) = xQ(x) \to P(0) = 0 \to k = -3$

Comment: What does P(x)=xQ(x) mean?

Comment: When you divide your polynomial $p(x)$ by $x$ you should get another polynomial $q(x)$ if it where to be divisible.

Comment: "P(x) = x Q(x)" means P(x) equals x times Q(x). For example, if Q(x) = x-1, P(x) = xQ(x) = x^2 - x.

Answer (score 0):

If $p(x)$ is divisible by $x$, $p(x) = q x$ where q is another polynomial in $x$. In particular, if $x=0$, $p(0) = q 0 = 0$. Then $p(0) = 15 - 5(-k) = 15 + k$. Now you know that $ 15 + k =0 $. So $k = -3.$

Comment: You lost me in your explanation with p(x) = qx. What does that mean and why does it matter? Specifically, what does "q is another polynomial in x
" mean?

Comment: @j76goatboy In your question you wrote "if $p(x)$ is divisible by $x$": do you know what does this mean? What is the definition of divisibility?

Comment: If x is divisible by y that means that y can go into x evenly, without any remainder. x/y has a remainder of 0. Applying this to the problem, the result of plugging x into the equation p(x) is divisible by x. I don't know why thats important though.

Comment: Why does the constant have to be zero if p(x) is divisible by x?

Comment: "If x is divisible by y that means that y can go into x evenly, without any remainder". What does "go into x evenly" mean? Write this using an equation. @j76goatboy

Comment: @avid19 x/y = floor(x/y)

Comment: @j76goatboy What is the floor of a polynomial?

Comment: @avid19 I'm flooring the result of the output/input. p(x)/x = floor(p(x)/x)

Comment: @j76goatboy You just restated what you said. WHAT IS THE FLOOR OF A POLYNOMIAL? For example what is the floor of $x^4+3x+4$?

Comment: @j76goatboy, when dealing with integers, we learn that a = bq + r, a is the dividend, b is the divisor, q is the quotient and r is  the remainder. That is an analogy between that and the problem you mentioned.

Comment: "q is a polynomial in x" means that q is a polynomial and q depends on x, examples, q(x) = x, q(x) = x^2+3, etc.

Comment: @avid19 I dont think you can floor a polynomial. That's not what I intended to say. You can floor the output of a polynomial. Ex: x^2 + 2x + 3    x = 5    5^2 + 2(5) + 3 = 38   floor(38/5) The constant of is polynomial isnt 0 because floor(38/5) != 38/5

Comment: @j76goatboy What is "the output of a polynomial"?

Comment: @avid19 I accidently posted the comment without finishing it, its finished now.

Comment: @j76goatboy You're talking about a number being divisible by another number. The $x$'s in polynomials need not be numbers at all! They are simply placeholders. When we say that a polynomial $a(x)$ is divisible by another polynomial $b(x)$, the only thing that this could possibly mean is that $a(x)=b(x)q(x)$ for another polynomial $q(x)$. This is the definition of divisibility.

Answer (score 0):

When it says $p(x)$ is divisible by $x$ it means everything in the equation must go away, otherwise saying everything must have an $x$ in the term. In the expanded which is $p(x) = 3 x^{2} + 25 x + 15 + 5 k$, $15$ and $5 k$ need to go away because they are NOT divisible by $x$. So you set $15 + 5 k=0$ and solve. You should end up with $k = -3$ and that's your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful explanations, here is my twist on describing the logic...

If something can be nicely divisible by a quantity then that means the remainder must be zero.  Example: 21 can be nicely divisible by 3, 21/3 = 7 with a remainder of 0 ("7 R 0", or 7 + 0/3).  Contrary, 22 cannot be nicely divisible by 3, 22/3 does not have a remainder of zero, 22/3 = "7 R 1", or 7 + 1/3.

Go back to the problem and use this reasoning as a template for the solution.

Since we know that p(x) is divisible by x (nicely), then we know that the quantity that remains in terms of x must be equal to zero.  Use the expanded version of p(x) then divide it by x.  Notice that only one component of this result is left with "x" in the denominator, (15+5k)/x .  In other words, because (15+5k)/x is the only component with "x" in the denominator, it is not "nice" and is the remainder.

The problem tell us that the remainder must be "0" (because p(x) is divisible by x).

So, the simple equation, (15+5k)/x, must be equal to 0.  Now just solve for k.

I hope this long explanation helps... it helped with my son's understanding.

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math, thank you.